# Zend Loader Problem

Tags: php, zend-framework

Well this question maybe asked for hunderds time. But I could not make it work.
There is my directory list:

```
--main/
---- Zend/
---- dir1/
---- dir2/
```

And this is my set include path configuration:

```
set_include_path(PATH_SEPARATOR
            . dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Zend' . PATH_SEPARATOR
            . get_include_path());
```

I also try adding all directories seperatly to the path.
But apache insists on giving these error:

> Warning: require_once(Zend/Loader.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\main\Zend\Translate.php on line 25 Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Zend/Loader.php' (include_path=';C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\main\Zend;.;C:\php\pear') in C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\main\Zend\Translate.php on line 25

Which is thrown from the php file which is in `dir1` on these lines:

```
include_once '../Zend/Locale.php';
include_once '../Zend/Translate.php'; //this is the line
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have a relative to current file include path, one of the two Zend classes, which is running:

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
```

is resolving to htdocs\main\Zend\Zend\Loader.php

To fix, remove the DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Zend', then also your include_once's can be

```
require_once 'Zend/Locale.php';
require_once 'Zend/Translate.php';
```

Note I changed to require_once as include_once will carry on the script even if the include fails, which is not recommended.